# Updated: Why relationship works when user is Admin, but won`t when Regular user?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have 3 models: User, Role and Currency. I am confused about relationship between them.

Then User is Admin this works:

```
Auth::user()->currency->symbol)
```

When regular User I get error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

if dd(Auth::user()) it show user, but cant access to relationship with model Currency. Why it is so?

User model relationship:

```
    public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id');
}
```

Currency model relationship:

```
    public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by_id');
}
```

If you need extra information, let me know.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User model**

```
public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
}
```

**Currency model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'created_by_id');
}
```

Going with an assumption that your `User` model has an attribute `currency_id`

Comment: Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Update your question with the code where you get that error

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Post your `error` stacktrace to https://paste.laravel.io/, save it, and post the link in your question. **Before that please update your Currency and User models like in my answer**

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->belongsTo(TABLE, FORIEGN KEY, TABLE KEY);
```

refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

User model

```
public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id', 'id');
}
```

Currency model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'created_by_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Updated my question